# drawing tree using tikz, child overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-qtree

I am trying to draw a tree but unfortunately i have some childs overlap each other,I increased the **sibling distance** , even i have used the option **scale** but i have the same problem. here is my code :

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,11pt,french]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=.6]
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=60mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=30mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[sibling distance=20mm] 

 \node{country}  
   child{node{name}child{node{ France }}}
   child{ node{city}child{node{ Paris }}}
  child{ node{region}child{node{name}child{node{ Nord-Pas De Calais }}}child{node{population}child{node{ 3996 }}}
  child{node{city}child{node{ Lille }}}}child{node{region}child{node{name}child{node{ Valle du Rhone }}}child{node{city}child{node{ Lyon }}}child{node{city}child{node{ Valence }}}}; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

and the result is

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe not as nice looking a tree, but a lot faster to input.  The `tikz-qtree` package is designed to optimize the spacing between nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[level 1/.style={level distance=1.5cm}]
\Tree
[.country 
  [.name France ] [.city Paris ] [.region 
                      [.name {Nord-Pas de Calais} ] 
                      [.population 3996 ] 
                      [.city Lille  ]
                   ] 
                   [.region 
                       [.name {Valle du Rhone } ] 
                      [.city Lyon ] 
                      [.city Valence ]
                  ]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 19):

An answer from the *future* (using `lualatex` and incoming `graphdrawing` libraries from CVS version of TikZ/pgf):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}%
    [tree layout,level distance=10mm,text depth=.1em,text height=.8em]
    \node{country}
    child{node{name}
      child{node{France}}
    }
    child{node{city}
      child{node{Paris}}
    }
    child{node{region}
      child{node{name}
        child{node{Nord-Pas De Calais}}
      }
      child{node{population}
        child{node{3996}}
      }
      child{node{city}
        child{node{Lille}}
      }
    }
    child{node{region}
      child{node{name}
        child{node{Vallee du Rhone}}
      }
      child{node{city}
        child{node{Lyon}}
      }
      child{node{city}
        child{node{Valence}}
      }
    }; 
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here's the result:
[image]

A compact version (using incoming `graphs` library):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}%
    [tree layout,level distance=10mm,text depth=.1em,text height=.8em]
    \graph[fresh nodes] {
      country -- {
        name -- France,
        city -- Paris,
        region -- {
          name -- "Nord-Pas De Calais",
          population -- 3996,
          city -- Lille
        },
        region -- {
          name -- "Valle du Rhone",
          city -- Lyon,
          city -- Valence
        }
      }
    };
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So this tikz library will only work with luatex? That's an odd dependency for a library to have, IMO.

Comment: @AlanMunn  extract from incoming pgfmanual: "Unlike the rest of pgf and TikZ, which is implemented purely in TEX, the graph drawing algorithms
are simply too complex to by implemented directly in TEX. Instead, the programming language Lua is used..."

Comment: From a UI perspective, it might be helpful to have a `\uselualibrary`command to make the luatex requirement explicit to users.  Otherwise I can see a big industry here answering "why doesn't my tikz document compile" :)  (Although I guess a big console message will suffice.)

Comment: @AlanMunn The big console message is: "! Package pgf Error: You need to run LuaTeX to use the graph drawing library."

Comment: Dependencies aside, the output is amazing. This is a huge gain for TikZ imho, making this much easier.

Answer (score 13):

I don't see any problems if I manually tune and do some structuring in the code. Actually if I remove the scale everything works just fine. If you want to scale the picture, you need to add `transform shape` option next to the scaling option.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} %[scale=.6,transform shape] %<-- uncomment this to see the effect
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[sibling distance=52mm] 
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[sibling distance=18mm] 

 \node{country} 
  child{node{name} child{ node{ France }}}
  child{node{city} child{node{ Paris }}}
  child{node{region} 
     child{node{name}
     child{node{ Nord-Pas De Calais }}}
     child{node{population} child{node{ 3996 }}}
     child{node{city} child{node{ Lille }}}
  } 
  child{node{region}
      child{node{name}   child{node{ Valle du Rhone }}} 
      child{node{city} child{node{ Lyon }}} 
      child{node{city}child{node{ Valence }}}
  }; 
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Third level sibling distance won't work if you have just one sibling for each parent.

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to use package [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest),
its syntax is similar, although not the same, to the one used with `tikz-qtree` and its main goal is to build compact trees. Take a look at next code and compare the results with the images provided by the other answerers.

`Forest` already loads `TikZ` and environment `forest` creates a `tikzpicture`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[country 
  [name [France]] [city[ Paris ]] [region 
                      [name [Nord-Pas de Calais] ] 
                      [population [3996] ] 
                      [city [Lille]  ]
                   ] 
                   [region 
                       [name [Valle du Rhone] ] 
                      [city [Lyon] ] 
                      [city [Valence] ]
                  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass[openright,a4paper,10pt,french]{report}%%

\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,automata,shadows,fit,shapes}
 \usepackage{amsmath}   
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\newcommand{\highlight}[1]{%
  \ooalign{\hss\makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{green!30}{red!40}{$#1$}}\hss\cr\phantom{$#1$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{   
\begin{tikzpicture} [font=\small]
\tikzset{level 1/.style={sibling distance=36ex}}
\tikzset{level 2/.style={sibling distance=13ex}}

 \node{country}  
  child{node{name}child{node{ France }}}
  child{ node{city}child{node{ Paris }}}
  child{ node{region}child{node{name}child{node{ Nord-Pas De Calais }}}child{node{population}child{node{ 3996 }}}
  child{node{city}child{node{ Lille }}}}child{node{region}child{node{name}child{node{ Valle du Rhone }}}child{node{city}child{node{ Lyon }}}child{node{city}child{node{ Valence }}}}; 
 \end{tikzpicture} }

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why you put the document in landscape ? it doesn't work when i delete landscape

Comment: I think it's difficult to put this tree on a normal page. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Another way of drawing this tree by using the [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package:
Please note that you can use `\istb<sibling distance=...>` to change the distance between some nodes.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}   

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\tikzset{ellipse node/.style={rectangle node,outer sep=2pt,draw=none}}
\xtdistance{10mm}{52mm}
\istrooto(0){country} 
  \istb<sibling distance=20mm>\istb<sibling distance=20mm>\istb\istb\endist
\xtdistance{10mm}{18mm}
\istrooto(1)(0-1){name} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(1-1)(1-1){France} \endist
\istrooto(2)(0-2){city}\istb \endist
  \istrooto(2-1)(2-1){Paris} \endist
\istrooto(3)(0-3){region} \istb\istb\istb\endist
\istrooto(3a)(3-1){name} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(3a-1)(3a-1){Nord-Pas De Calais} \endist
\istrooto(3b)(3-2){population} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(3b-1)(3b-1){3996} \endist
\istrooto(3c)(3-3){city} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(3c-1)(3c-1){Lille} \endist
\istrooto(4)(0-4){region} \istb\istb\istb\endist
\istrooto(4a)(4-1){name} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(4a-1)(4a-1){Valle du Rhone} \endist
\istrooto(4b)(4-2){city} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(4b-1)(4b-1){Lyon} \endist
\istrooto(4c)(4-3){city} \istb\endist
  \istrooto(4c-1)(4c-1){Valence} \endist
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```