# Tree in Tikz with unwanted crossing nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am trying to make a simple tree using Tikz, but I have some problems with the right position (level) of the right side of the tree. How can this be fixed?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    sibling distance=10em,
    every node/.style = {%
        shape=rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw,
        align=center,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!20
   }]]

\node {root}
    child { node {A (level 1)}
        child { node {A.A (level 2)}
            child { node {A.A.A (level 3)} }
            child { node {A.A.B (level 3)} }
        }
        child { node {A.B (level 2)} }
        child { node {A.C (level 2)} }
    }
    child { node {B (level 1)}
        child { node {B.A (level 2)} }
        child { node {B.B (level 2)} }
        child { node {B.C (level 2)} }
    %} % comment, as it wouldn't typeset otherwise
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What it looks like at the moment:[image: error]

Comment: Please add a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: @OSjerick I have added the missing lines.

Comment: If you need to draw more trees, may be you could consider `forest`, it will solve this problem without your intervention: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60571/1952

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like this;

[image]
For this you need to increase sibling distance at level 1, and slightly reduce in level 2:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
level 1/.style = {sibling distance=24em},   % <-- added
level 2/.style = {sibling distance=8em},    % <-- added
level 3/.style = {sibling distance=9em},    % <-- added
    every node/.style = {%
        shape=rectangle,
        rounded corners,
        draw,
        align=center,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=blue!20
   }]]

\node {root}
    child { node {A (level 1)}
        child { node {A.A (level 2)}
            child { node {A.A.A (level 3)} }
            child { node {A.A.B (level 3)} }
        }
        child { node {A.B (level 2)} }
        child { node {A.C (level 2)} }
    }
    child { node[red] {B (level 1)}
        child { node {B.A (level 2)} }
        child { node {B.B (level 2)} }
        child { node {B.C (level 2)} }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is what I was looking for.